# React Native popup menu styling

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Currently my compontent looks like that

[image]

Is there any way, i can kinda cut off some of the top right corner of it?
So it will look something like this:
[image]

I am using react-native-popup-menu library and i don't know how to do it, is it even possible?

```
export function MenuComponentE1(props) {

  return (
        <Menu>
          <MenuTrigger>
            <View style={styles.budynekContainer}>
              <Image source={require("../ProjektAIDC/assets/raportPage/iconBudynek.png")} style={styles.Icons}/>
              <Text style={styles.budynekTekst}>{props.budTextProp}</Text>
            </View>
          </MenuTrigger>
          <MenuOptions optionsContainerStyle={{marginLeft: 70, marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: "lightgray", borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10, borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderTopRightRadius: 20}}>
            <MenuOption text={props.budTextProp} customStyles={{optionWrapper: {height: 60, backgroundColor: "lightgray", marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 5, marginRight: 5, marginBottom: 5}, optionText: {fontSize: 22, color: "#faf3ea"}}}/>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => props.setBudTextCallBack("budynek 1")} customStyles={{optionWrapper: {height: 30, backgroundColor: "silver", marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 5, marginRight: 5, marginBottom: 1}, optionText: {fontSize: 18, color: "#faf3ea"}}} text={"budynek 1"}>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => props.setBudTextCallBack("budynek 2")} customStyles={{optionWrapper: {height: 30, backgroundColor: "darkgray", marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 5, marginRight: 5, marginBottom: 1}, optionText: {fontSize: 18, color: "#faf3ea"}}} text={"budynek 2"}>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption onSelect={() => props.setBudTextCallBack("budynek 3")} customStyles={{optionWrapper: {height: 30, backgroundColor: "silver", marginLeft: 5, marginTop: 5, marginRight: 5, marginBottom: 1}, optionText: {fontSize: 18, color: "#faf3ea"}}} text={"budynek 3"}>
            </MenuOption>
          </MenuOptions>
        </Menu>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you put some of your code in your question?

Comment: Actually, i think i can maybe make this part transparent or something like that by playing with borderRight width. But then i can't set some border radius after this text "budynek 1" and it looks bad without it. I wish i could just change  width of this particular option's component, but it's wrapped in this MenuOptions container so it does nothing. I can't also change MenuOptions' container width because all options are wrapped by it.